# Why does "man" command disappear?

Tags: rhel, package-management, man

I find `man` command disappears on my `RHEL7`:

```
# man ls
bash: man: command not found...
# which man
/usr/bin/which: no man in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/gocode/bin:/root/bin:/opt/linuxki)
```

But `man` and `man-pages` are all on my box:

```
# yum install man
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package man-db-2.6.3-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
# yum install man-pages
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Where did `man` go?

**Update 1**:

Try to reinstall `man`, but it prompts following errors:

```
......
Running transaction
  Installing : man-db-2.6.3-9.el7.x86_64                                                                                                 1/1
Error unpacking rpm package man-db-2.6.3-9.el7.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/man: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : man-db-2.6.3-9.el7.x86_64                                                                                               1/1

Failed:
  man-db.x86_64 0:2.6.3-9.el7
```

**Update 2**

```
# ls -lt /usr/bin/man
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nan nan   81 Mar 24 22:30 man1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nan nan 4096 Mar 24 22:30 man7
# stat /usr/bin/man
  File: ‘/usr/bin/man’
  Size: 28              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 67811254    Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     nan)   Gid: ( 1000/     nan)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
Access: 2016-04-15 17:47:56.613595324 +0800
Modify: 2016-03-24 22:30:30.000000000 +0800
Change: 2016-04-08 11:08:45.605815500 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Can you add the output from `ls -l /usr/bin/man` to your question above (actually, include `stat /usr/bin/man` as well).

Comment: uninstall `man` ,remove `/usr/bin/man` and install `man-pages` then install `man`

Comment: @EightBitTony: Add output of `ls -l /usr/bin/man` and `stat /usr/bin/man`, thanks!

Comment: RPM uses `cpio` as it’s archive format, which is why we’re seeing a cpio error when trying to replace the file `/usr/bin/man`

Comment: Well, I don't know why - but your `/usr/bin/man` appears to be a directory, rather than a single executable.  It's almost as if someone has copied the man pages directory over /usr/bin/man.

Comment: @GAD3R it uses cpio which is why the error is cpio based, but the actual error is caused because it's trying to write a single file over a directory - why /usr/bin/man is a directory is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @EightBitTony Exactly!

Comment: What are the files inside /usr/bin/man/man1 and /usr/bin/man/man7? They may indicate a package with a faulty install script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I doubt we'll ever be able to tell you where it went, but you should just be able to reinstall it using `yum`.

`yum reinstall man`

`yum` doesn't check to see if files exist when you run `yum install`, it just checks a database of which packages have been installed.  If someone deletes all the files outside of the package manager, it won't know (you can get it to check, but it doesn't by default).  Using `yum reinstall` tells it to do the install even though it thinks the package is already there.

Depending on what has been deleted or removed, you may need to `yum reinstall ...` other things like `man-pages`.

*Updated in light of new information:*

For some reason, your `/usr/bin/man` is a directory, rather than a single file, and judging by the content it looks like someone has done something weird like `mv /usr/share/man /usr/bin` or something odd.

You're not going to be able to simply undo this - you need to investigate, see what's been broken or moved, and correct it.

You **might** just be able to remove `/usr/bin/man` and its contents and then re-install `man` and `man-pages` using `yum` but without more investigation it's not going to be clear.

Comment: I try to reinstall man, but it prompts "`unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/man: cpio: rename`" error. Could u help to check? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: @ Remove `/usr/bin/man` and reinstall `man` fix it, thx very much!

Comment: @NanXiao: If `/usr/bin/man` is a directory, who knows what else is screwed up? At this point, I'd recommend backing up your files and reinstalling the OS from scratch. And don't let your three-year-old play with a root shell next time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

RPM uses `cpio` as its archive format. That is why we’re seeing a `cpio` error when trying to replace the file `/usr/bin/man`.

You need to `remove` and `purge` `man` then you need to install `man-pages`.

Open the Terminal and type the following commands:

```
yum check-update
yum update
yum install man-pages
yum install man
```

Comment: The original question shows that `yum install man` and `yum install man-pages` didn't make any difference because `yum` thinks they are already installed.